# Php header redirect to $page2 variable

Tags: php

It is possible in any way to add an $ variable to this line:?

```
header( "refresh:2;url= /page2" );
```

**like this:**

```
$page2="home.php"

header( "refresh:2;url=<?php echo $page2  ?>" );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're over-thinking it.  You can use a variable directly in a double-quoted string:

```
header( "refresh:2;url=$page2" );
```

Or concatenate it in a single-quoted string:

```
header( 'refresh:2;url=' . $page2 );
```

There's no need to write PHP code *within* PHP code.  Just build your string from the values you have.